# AWS: what to use for GPU inference via rest api

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, gpu

I want to use AWS to inference a gpu model. I read that it is possible to use an EC2 instance for inference. But I do not need an instance which is running 24/7 because I offer a service, which may be used a couple of times each day. My model is quite complex and I want the inference time to be fast, so I probably need a gpu machine for it. The inference must be triggered over a rest api as e.g. AWS lambda. How would the price be calculated then? Just for inference time or 24/7 since the instance is always running?

I would like to use just AWS Lambda but Lambda does not support gpu. I read that Lambda can emulate the gpu via cpu. I would like to try this out, but where can I set this up?  I hope some of you can suggest me the right way, it also depends how the inferring time on EC2 will be calculated.

Best regards

Sony

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options.

1. If you can run it on CPU, you could use [SageMaker Serverless Inference Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/serverless-endpoints.html), but it does not support GPU.
2. If you must host it on a GPU, then you can use an [asynchronous endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/async-inference.html) - it's designed for large payloads, but when you need GPU, then its the best approach IMO, it provides capability to scale in to an instance count of zero when there are no requests to process, meaning that you won't be charged.
   The following blog has a good example of an implementation. It uses SageMaker Jumpstart, but you can use your own model and follow the same logic. https://aws.amazon.com/it/blogs/machine-learning/optimize-deployment-cost-of-amazon-sagemaker-jumpstart-foundation-models-with-amazon-sagemaker-asynchronous-endpoints/

Example of a policy that scales to zero:

```
response = client.put_scaling_policy(
    PolicyName="HasBacklogWithoutCapacity-ScalingPolicy",
    ServiceNamespace="sagemaker",  # The namespace of the service that provides the resource.
    ResourceId=resource_id,  # Endpoint name
    ScalableDimension="sagemaker:variant:DesiredInstanceCount",  # SageMaker supports only Instance Count
    PolicyType="StepScaling",  # 'StepScaling' or 'TargetTrackingScaling'
    StepScalingPolicyConfiguration={
        "AdjustmentType": "ChangeInCapacity", # Specifies whether the ScalingAdjustment value in the StepAdjustment property is an absolute number or a percentage of the current capacity. 
        "MetricAggregationType": "Average", # The aggregation type for the CloudWatch metrics.
        "Cooldown": 300, # The amount of time, in seconds, to wait for a previous scaling activity to take effect. 
        "StepAdjustments": # A set of adjustments that enable you to scale based on the size of the alarm breach.
        [ 
            {
              "MetricIntervalLowerBound": 0,
              "ScalingAdjustment": 1
            }
          ]
    },    
)
```

Then you create a CW alarm with your custom metrics

```
response = cw_client.put_metric_alarm(
    AlarmName=step_scaling_policy_alarm_name,
    MetricName='HasBacklogWithoutCapacity',
    Namespace='AWS/SageMaker',
    Statistic='Average',
    EvaluationPeriods= 2,
    DatapointsToAlarm= 2,
    Threshold= 1,
    ComparisonOperator='GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold',
    TreatMissingData='missing',
    Dimensions=[
        { 'Name':'EndpointName', 'Value':endpoint_name },
    ],
    Period= 60,
    AlarmActions=[step_scaling_policy_arn]
)
```